# How do I split a string to a LinkedList<int>?

Tags: c#

I have a string like this:

```
string myS = "20,        21,        22,        23,        24"
```

I want to get this:

```
LinkedList<int> myLL = new LinkedList<int>();
```

I tried this:

```
myLL = (LinkedList<int>)myS.Split(',').Select(n => int.Parse(n.Trim()));
```

It does not work, throw conversion error, what do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`LinkedList<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sb8tw8x.aspx) instead of casting:

```
var myLL = new LinkedList<int>(myS.Split(',').Select(n => int.Parse(n.Trim()));
```